# JPA Criteria subqueries combined with disjunction

Tags: jpa, subquery, criteria

i have a little problem with JPA criteria API. I have one Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person implements Serializable
{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "person_gen")
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "NAME")
private String name;

@Column(name = "AGE")
private Integer = age;

public Long getId()
{
    return this.id;
}

public String getName()
{
    return this.name;
}

public Integer getAge()
{
    return this.age;
}
}
```

And now i want make a query similar to this:

```
select * from Person where 
(Person.Id) in (select Person.Id from Person where Person.Id = 15625) or 
(Person.Id) in (select Person.Id from Person where Person.Name = 'Name') or
(Person.Id) in (select Person.Id from Person where Person.Age = 28)
```

There are some subqueries with an 'or' statement. How to do this with JPA criteria query? I have tried many things an it does not work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try it without the unnecessary subqueries: select * from Person where 
Person.Id = 15625 or Person.Name = 'Name' or Person.Age = 28

Answer (score 0):

Your particular query really is unnecessarily complex. Your `IN` predicates can all be removed and replaced by the following, much simpler predicates:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM Person
WHERE Id = 12625
OR Name = 'Name'
OR Age = 28
```

This should be much simpler to translate to a JPA criteria query.